# parentheses only used for capture group in regular expression matching?

Tags: regex

I have a confusion when reading regular expression written by others, my question is parentheses `()` could only be used for capture group? Or we could use it to make regular expression more elegant to read by group logical set of operations together, especially for long regular expression?

I ask this since I sometimes see after people write long regular expression, they write additional parentheses even if they do not need to know capture group match information -- I mean even if they just need to know if the whole regular expression match or not, they still add some parentheses.

Comment: But you do mean only parentheses like `(`…`)` and not like `(?:`…`)`, `(?!`…`)`, `(?=`…`)` and similar ones, don’t you? Because those do have a different special meaning.

Comment: @Xufox, I only mean `(...)`, thanks for asking and vote up. If you have any thoughts to my original question, it will be great.

Comment: Those groups can be used with quantifiers, e.g. `(?:ab)+` for a repeated sequence of `ab`s. `(ab)+` would do the same thing but additionally capture the group. When I personally write regexes, I try to avoid unnecessary capturing groups.

Comment: @Xufox, thanks and at least adding `()` has no harm and improve readability, correct?

Comment: Adding `(`…`)` in the correct positions — i.e. not between any regex symbols that shouldn’t be separated — does no harm, as long as you know which groups you want to capture or don’t want to capture. Too many, however, decrease readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses are used for grouping and that would make regex engine capture the sub pattern inside the parentheses.

If you don't want to capture the text inside using **non-capturing group** by using this syntax:

```
(?:...)
```

This will also save some memory while processing the long and complex regex.

See more on [Non capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

A basic & simple example on how ad where `()` should be placed carefully if regex is this

```
^\w+|\d+$
```

Where we are selecting word at start or digits at end in the input:

```
foo -a123 bar baz 123
```

Thus we are matching `foo` and `123`.

If you place brackets `()` like this:

```
^(\w+|\d+)$
```

then your match will fail as we are asserting presence of both anchors `^` and `$` around a word OR a number in input.

Correct regex with brackets would be:

```
(?:^\w+|\d+$)
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, vote up. I know non-capturing group and used it. My question is, if I do not care sub pattern captured in a regular expression and I only care if the whole regular expression match or not, it is correct to use `()` just to make long regular expression easier to read?

Comment: Yes you can definitely use `()` or better `(?:)` to make it more readable as that will not change the behavior of your regex. But just be careful how you place `()` in your regex so that overall meaning of regex doesn't change by seeing what comes before and after `()`

Comment: Thanks anubhava, vote up for your reply. What do you mean doesn't change by seeing what comes before and after `()`? Could you show me an example? I am not aware `()` will change the logical results.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I mis-understand your points a bit. An example will be great. :)

Comment: I've added a simple examples of using `()`

Comment: The example looks nice. For your comments "are asserting ^ and $ for both word and numbers", I think you mean either matching any string starts with word or number, and ends with word or number, which is not the original purpose of the regex, correct?

Comment: I meant by placing anchors `^` and `$` around `^(\w+|\d+)$` we are actually enforcing both anchors around a word or number. Thus the only input we can match now is just a word or a number in the line. Where as original regex `^\w+|\d+$` is matching differently by matching a word at start OR a number in the end.

Comment: Got it, thanks anubhava, vote for your example, and it is a bit tricky and needs to be careful as you suggested. And in your example, `(\w+|\d+)` could also be served as the capture group in case we need to know what are matched, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct and to to save some memory you can optimize it by using `(?:\w+|\d+)`